# Hierarchical structure in treeview (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I want to visualize a hierarchical structure of objects in a treeview. I know that there are plenty of tutorials out there describing how to do that. In principle I think I even know what to do, but I am stuck. I hope someone can point out my mistake.

This is "myObject":

```
    private int _id;
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            if(this._id != value)
            {
                this.OnPropertyChanging("Id");
                this._id = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public virtual string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._name;
        }
        set
        {
            if(this._name != value)
            {
                this.OnPropertyChanging("name");
                this._name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("name");
            }
        }
    }

    private int? _parentId;
    public virtual int? parentId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._parentId;
        }
        set
        {
            if(this._parentId != value)
            {
                this.OnPropertyChanging("parentId");
                this._parentId = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("parentId");
            }
        }
    }

    private MyObject _myObject1;
    public virtual MyObject MyParentObject
    {
        get
        {
            return this._myObject1;
        }
        set
        {
            if(this._myObject1 != value)
            {
                this.OnPropertyChanging("MyParentObject");
                this._myObject1 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("MyParentObject");
            }
        }
    }

    private IList<MyObject> _myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
    public virtual IList<MyObject> MyChildObjects
    {
        get
        {
            return this._myObjects;
        }
    }
```

The important thing here is the list of child objects called "MyChildObjects".

The XAML looks as follows:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding myObjects}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding myObjects/MyChildObjects}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

My problem now is that the treeview only shows a flat structure of all objects. The mistake most likely is in the XAML file, but I am not able to figure it out. What do I have to change to have the hierarchy in the treeview?

Thank you for your help!
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in `TreeView.Resources` for `DataType` of `MyObject`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding myObjects}">
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyObject}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyChildObjects}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

also your `ItemsSource` path is wrong. When you use `myObjects/` it means current item of `myObjects`. What you need is just `ItemsSource="{Binding MyChildObjects}`

[`Binding.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When the source is a collection view, the current item can be specified with a slash (/). For example, the clause Path=/ sets the binding to the current item in the view. When the source is a collection, this syntax specifies the current item of the default collection view.

Comment: Is `DataType` required in this situation (where the treeview will contain instances of a single type)?

Comment: When you specify `DataTemplate` in `Resources` you must either specify `DataType` or `x:Key`

Answer (score 0):

You've set up the ItemsSource, but I think you will also need to set up an ItemTemplate inside the HierachicalDataTemplate. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).